# Passing a string to a handler function in Go

Tags: http, go, redirect

I have a generic Webserver which I want to use on different domains / servers.
For setting up each server I simply read a JSON config file with all necessary information. One would be for example the redirect for all traffic which reaches port 80 and forward it to a TLS service. Since I don't want to make the config object global. How can I pass the content from my inputFromConfigFile to the redirectTLS function?

Here is an example:

```
func main(){
  var inputFromConfigFile = "https://www.example.com:443"


  go func() {
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", http.HandlerFunc(redirectTLS)); err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("ListenAndServe error: %v", err)
    }
  }()
}

//Pass the above string to this function:

func redirectTLS(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.Redirect(w, r, "https://www.example.com:443"+r.RequestURI,http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}
```

Comment: If it's a JSON config file, you should parse it once and pass the object/map to the handler, rather than passing the string so each handler has to parse it repeatedly

Comment: This is what I actually wann to do. For the sake of simplicity I just used a string in the example…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `redirectTLS` as an inline closure function directly in main:

```
var inputFromConfigFile = "https://www.example.com:443"

go func() {
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, inputFromConfigFile+r.RequestURI, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("ListenAndServe error: %v", err)
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom Handler (could be implemented as a struct) as long as it matches the http.Handler interface. The config could be saved inside the Handler as a struct field.

```
type Handler struct {
  // config goes here
}

func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // anything that handler needs to do here
}
```

Example: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#example-Handle

Answer (score 0):

I would make the config object global.

Otherwise, you can define a function that accepts the config as an argument, and returns a handler function that closes over the configuration object:

```
var inputFromConfigFile = "https://www.example.com:443"

http.ListenAndServe(":80", createHandler(inputFromConfigFile))

// ...

func createHandler(config string) http.HandlerFunc {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, config+r.RequestURI,http.StatusMovedPermanently)
  })
}
```